# Is the center of mass of a convex shape can be calculate just by its sphere?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, convex-geometry

I want to calculate the center of mass of a convex shape with finite number of points (it is actually pixels in a picture this is why it is discrete).

Let say the shape is convex (it is not but pretty close to it so we can let go of extreme cases).

Can I calculate the mean value of the sphere points (points that are on the border of the shape, they have neighbors which are not part of the shape) instead of using all the points?

It will reduce my time complexity significantly.

It feels like it can work but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Ok now my guts changed: if you take A long and narrow isosceles triangle, the mass point of the sphere would be pretty close to the middle, where the mass point of the whole shape is probably third way from the base if I am not wrong.

Comment: When you say "mass point" do you mean "centre of mass"?  When you say "its sphere", do you mean the "minimal bounding sphere" (or circle in two dimensions)?  If so, then no, that will give a different answer, as your edit suggested

Comment: Yes I meant center of mass. By sphere I mean as "all the pixels that has neighbor pixels which are not part of the shape". I will clarify it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The center of mass of border points is different, in general, from that of the whole shape.

You could instead divide your shape into "simple" pieces (for instance rectangles and triangles) for which it is easy to compute the center of mass. The overall center of mass is then the average of the positions of the centres of the pieces, weighted by the areas of the pieces.

Comment: So there are some simple shapes, I guess symetric on 2 axis, which it is true that the center of mass of sphere is equal to center of mass of the whole shape. If I can split my shape into few rectangles I may be able to compute the center of mass without going through all the points. But splitting the shape into rectangles might be hard to do

Comment: Well if it is possible to set the figure such that its is simetric on x and on y, then for sure the center of mass is the same for the sphere and the hole figure, cause for both its the center of the shape

Comment: Triangles would work too, it's just slightly more complex to compute the area.